# In SpringMVC, why is my @RequestParam disappearing?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I find a strange question in SpringMVC.  I use postman to send a request with

[image: these details]

but when i debug I see [image: this]

why status become 'status '

This is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/publishCallback" , method = {RequestMethod.POST, 
RequestMethod.GET})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseData publicCallback( PublishCallBackVo publishCallBackVo, 
HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    logger.info("传入的请求参数"+request.getParameterMap());
    String status_ = request.getParameterMap().get("status ")[0];
    publishCallBackVo.setStatus(status_);
    projectPublishService.publishCallBack(publishCallBackVo);
    return ResponseData.success();
}

public class PublishCallBackVo {
    private String id;
    private String status;
    private String project;
    private String envType;
    private String result;
    private String projectType;
    private String tarName;
    private String appTag;
    private String deployType;
    private String ip;
```

Comment: can you check your request you are sending from the postman, maybe there will be any whitespace in that field

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `[0]` from this line of code

```
String status_ = request.getParameterMap().get("status ")[0];
```

**Note:** You have space after status in get.
Hence the code will become

```
String status_ = request.getParameterMap().get("status");
```

**Reason:** 
[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object))
If that doesn't work, as you are accessing it like the list, then replace `[0]` with `[1]` in your code. And do let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/publishCallback" , method = {RequestMethod.POST, 
RequestMethod.GET})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseData publicCallback( PublishCallBackVo publishCallBackVo, 
HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
logger.info("传入的请求参数"+request.getParameterMap());
String status_ = request.getParameterMap().get("status ");
if(status_!=null && status_!=""){
  publishCallBackVo.setStatus(status_);
  projectPublishService.publishCallBack(publishCallBackVo);
}
return ResponseData.success();
}
```